# How to do something when exiting or crashing a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that downloads some files, uses them and do other stuff, but i need those files to be automatically deleted when the program closes/exits, either manually pressing the X or terminating it or from an unhandled exeption or crash.

I tried with "atexit" but didn't work. or only works when closing manually, i need to also do it on unexpected crashes

Comment: I think https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html is what you are searching for.